# Regex to Match Hashtags in string that contain no more than 1 space

Tags: regex

What I'm looking to do is match hashtags in a string, but the hashtag may have a space in it: `#brown fox`. Most hashtags are single words, `#brown`, `#fox`, but some were improperly formatted and resulted in spaces being entered.

The hashtags that have spaces are only allowed to be two words, so `#space suit` is allowed, but `#brown fox jumps` is not allowed.

1. The quick #**brown** #**fox** #**jumps** over the lazy dog.

`brown, fox, jumps`

2. The quick #**brown fox** #**jumps** over the lazy dog.

`brown fox, jumps`

3. The quick #**brown fox** #**jumps** over the lazy #**dog**.

`brown fox, jumps, dog`

If there is a hashtag, followed by one word, then followed by a hashtag, then we can assume the word is for that hashtag. Otherwise, we shouldn't capture it in the group.

Here is what I've tried so far, but clearly it's nowhere close to what I need:
https://regex101.com/r/vHOCaf/1

```
(\#+\w{2,})|(\#([\w]){2,}\s{0,1}([\w]){2,})
```

Comment: As of I understood the two word tag can only be matched if followed by another tag, Is that right?

Comment: @JorgeCampos that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need must have a positive lookahead to not match a hashtag followed by a word without followed by another hashtag:

```
#\w+\b(?:\s\w+\b(?=\s#\w+))?
```

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IxtWDzre_EEvv7VW)

Comment: Works like it should! Thanks @Jorge. Appreciate you taking the time. Also thanks for making me aware of Debuggex... didn't know this site existed until now.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want: `/#(?:\w+\b)(?: ?\w*\b)/g`, it will match at most 2 words after `#` or only one if the second word has a `#` also.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/Bq0qNM/2

---

**[EDIT] change regex to not match a second word if there is no `#` after it:**

`/#(?:(?:\w+\b \w+\b)(?= #|$)|\w+\b)/g`

See result here: https://regex101.com/r/Bq0qNM/3

---

**[EDIT] a shorter one**
`/#(?:\w+ ?\w+(?= #|$)|\w+\b)/g`, https://regex101.com/r/Bq0qNM/4

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I downvoted it because it do not comply with the rules stated. A hash tag with two words can only be matched if it is followed by another hashtag, in your regex it is matching `#jumps over` which is wrong.

Comment: Great antoni! I removed the downvote :) and upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
#(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)
```

Comment: I think the only problem with this is that it groups a second word even though it isn't followed by a #hashtag. For example, it groups: #brown fox jumps, when it should only group the word "fox" if the word "jumps" is a hashtag.

Comment: So for #brown fox jumps, the hashtag is only #brown and not #brown fox?  I think the definition of your hashtag is ambiguous here.

Comment: it's not about how to "do it right", this question is about solving a problem I caused in my data set. Since I know how I messed up my data set, I need to reverse it. The parameters I've listed above are the rules that I used the first time... Does that make sense?

Comment: To allow this kind of match, using lookahead should be considered, like the answer from Jorge Campos.